# How can I page through data using nHibernate using a CTE?

Tags: sql-server-2005, nhibernate

Is there any example code someone can show me that will page through data in a given table, and use CTE's under the hood?

Is nhibernate suppose to work across various databases out of the box? I am using MS SQL Server 2008 now, but what if the client wants to use Oracle someday?

Answer (score 2):

For paging you just define start and end result in the query:

```
IQuery q = sess.CreateQuery("from DomesticCat cat");
q.SetFirstResult(20);
q.SetMaxResults(10);
IList cats = q.List();
```

See the [reference docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-queryinterface)

NHibernate is supposed to work across various databases. Many dialects are implemented and available out of the box. SqlServer and Oracle are both very well supported.

See the [reference docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#configuration-optional-dialects) for a list of supported dialects.

Comment: The way Stefan shows would be the best. I have no clue why you involve Common Table Expressions in the questions, there's no need for that.

Comment: Rune, CTE's would be more effecient.  Stefan, what does the sql look like?

Comment: Try it, I can't tell you by heart, it looks rather complicated. But it uses SQL features from the underlying dbms.